# How to use extraction operator to get multiple values from method of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, extraction-operator

Like we use  in cin:

```
cin >> a >> b;
```

to get multiple values from input stream and insert them to multiple variables.
How can we implement this method in our own class? To get multiple values from it.
I tried this as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925866/c-extraction-operator-for-class-functions):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class example {
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, example& exam);
    private:
        int my = 2;
        int my2 = 4;
};

istream& operator>> (istream& is, example& exam) {
    is >> exam.my >> exam.my2;
    return is;  
}

int main() {
    example abc;
    int s, t;

    abc >> s >> t;
    cout << s << t;
}
```

But getting error "no match for operator>> (operand types are 'example' and 'int')"

PS: I know the alternate ways but I want to know this specific way of doing this, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insertion operator you defined works with `std::istream` as a source rather than you own class. Although I think your objective is ill-advised, you can create similar operators for your class. You'll need some entity with a suitable state as chained operators should extract different values.

I wouldn't use this for any sort of production set up but it certainly can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

template <int Index, typename... T>
class extractor {
    std::tuple<T const&...> values;
public:
    extractor(std::tuple<T const&...> values): values(values) {}
    template <typename A>
    extractor<Index + 1, T...> operator>> (A& arg) {
        arg = std::get<Index>(values);
        return extractor<Index + 1, T...>{ values };
    }
};

template <typename... T>
extractor<0, T...> make_extractor(T const&... values) {
    return extractor<0, T...>(std::tie(values...));
}

class example {
private:
    int my = 2;
    int my2 = 4;
    double my3 = 3.14;
public:
    template <typename A>
    extractor<0, int, double> operator>> (A& arg) {
        arg = my;
        return make_extractor(this->my2, this->my3);
    }
};

int main() {
    example abc;
    int s, t;
    double x;

    abc >> s >> t >> x;
    cout << s << " " << t << " " << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand how this is not a better idea in programming but I just had the urge to know it and was searching since an hour.

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract data from an `example` into an `int`. Instead, you wrote code to extract data from an `istream` into an `example`. That's why the right function cannot be found: you did not write one.

If you really wish to allow `abc >> s >> t` to work, you're going to have to define an `operator>>(example&, int&)` and add stream/cursor semantics to your class, to keep track at each step of what's been extracted so far. That really sounds like more trouble than it's worth.